# How to check if string is SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(64)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, secure-random

The string:

```
SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(64)
#=> "nItIZhCvbne9zjU4JUWJOL46y53ERfmuQQW_FN4_ymk2EdbQr1NYOXTJVIeUWXhvRCe4OU3Is2ZEaHpiXXGYxw"
```

[Random::Formatted.`urlsafe_base64`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/Random/Formatter.html#method-i-urlsafe_base64) implementation:

```
def urlsafe_base64(n=nil, padding=false)
  s = [random_bytes(n)].pack("m0")
  s.tr!("+/", "-_")
  s.delete!("=") unless padding
  s
end
```

So the question is basically what title says: is there a sane way to check whether string is generated with above method?

Maybe with some regexp? From docs:

> The result may contain A-Z, a-z, 0-9, “-” and “_”. “=” is also used if
>   padding is true.

I would think there is not, because string is just a string, but I need to know if I can rely on anything more than its length while checking it.

Initial problem is that Rollbar gem filters API request Header with `***`, and I'd like to change that so that I can see first `n` characterss of api token to track who made the failing request.

Comment: You can also check if all symbols are uppercase or lowercase letters or `+` or  `\\`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna answer the literal question:

> is there a sane way to check whether string is generated with above method?

Yes, there is. Kind of. Depends on where your boundaries of "sane" are. :)

Adapted from http://www.schneems.com/2016/01/25/ruby-debugging-magic-cheat-sheet.html

```
require 'objspace'
require 'securerandom'

ObjectSpace.trace_object_allocations_start

Kernel.send(:define_method, :sup) do |obj|
  puts "#{ ObjectSpace.allocation_sourcefile(obj) }:#{ ObjectSpace.allocation_sourceline(obj) }"
end

str = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(64)

sup str
# >> /Users/sergio/.rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/securerandom.rb:169
```

Comment: Hm, I might have added some context to the question. Initial problem is that Rollbar gem filters API request Header with `***`, and I'd like to change that so that I can see first, say, 5 chars of api token to track who made the failing request.

Comment: Well, that's an entirely different problem, it seems.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko: also you meant to say "I should have added" instead of "might have added" :)

Comment: My api tokens are generated with `SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(64)`, but having your answer (cool stuff btw!) I see how not adding these details to the question in the first place made it wrongly understood..

Comment: @AndreyDeineko: maybe just patch the rollbar and make a special case for your api key header (detect by name, not by value format)

Comment: I am looking into [this module](https://github.com/rollbar/rollbar-gem/blob/bf6d439be15455b557886fc73304ba00303aa278/lib/rollbar/scrubbers.rb) and my first though was to patch it, but here it's based on value. But i see what you mean, will look if I can do that. Thx!

Comment: @AndreyDeineko: yes, indeed. Well, I'd use a regex in this case.